# R: Knitr Syntax expression as text

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'm using the knitr package with RStudio and want to write the following expression as text in my output pdf file:

```
\Sexpr{pi}
```

I tried the LaTeX math mode:

```
$\Sexpr{pi}$
```

but it will give me the value and not the text.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49131/inserting-latex-code-into-latex

Comment: that worked with \Sexpr{}, but \Sexpr{pi} will still print the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write `\textbackslash{}Sexpr\{pi\}`.

Comment: The OP could enclose that with `\texttt{}` to differentiate code.